# How are ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and google cloud project/instance level metadata related?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine

From what I read, `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` just take what is in the project level metadata. If i delete an entry from the console, it disappears from the `authorized_keys` file too.
However, if i delete from the `authorized_keys` file, the console still shows the entry with the deleted public key.

Once I exit the ssh session, I'm then not able to go back in with either `gcloud compute ssh user@instance_name` or `ssh user@instance_ip`. Why is this so?

I had to then go to the console and delete that entry (that i previously removed by editting `authorized_keys` file directly) and only now `gcloud compute ssh user@instance_name` works properly again, helping me add my `google_compute_engine.pub` into project metadata so `ssh user@instance_ip` now works too.

P.S I'm unfamiliar with how instance level metadata works so only experimented with project level metadata ssh keys. If any answer can comment whether your answer applies to instance level too that'll be great.

Answer (score 0):

One can provide SSH keys either on the project or instance level. Please don't edit files, but add them on the GCE console, becaause they're generally managed by GCP. So that one can even eg. generate and provision a new key, run a script, let the key expire. Alike this one does not have to store the key anywhere ...which is quite unlike a traditional VM. The amount of keys one can add into instance meta-data is limited.